# Why Octopus binding variables does not work?

Tags: variables, binding, octopus

I have just started with Octopus deployment. 
I tried to add binding variables and re-deploy my web as below snapshot. Unfortunately, my binding does not work.
Any idea? Many thanks!

[image]

---

Added more info @ 17 Jan 2020
Creating a new release version makes it work. Look like the variable is being cached somewhere. There should be a manner to clear the cache; unluckily I have not figured it out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update variable value in existing release using below steps.

> 1) Go to your existing release page by clicking on release
>
> 2) Under "**Variable Snapshot**", There is button called "**UPDATE
>   VARIABLES**", Just click and confirm.

For reference :

[image]